# How to pass ViewModel from view to action use @Url.action in mvc4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I create a ViewModel:

```
public class TestViewModel
    {

        public int RegionId { get; set; }
        public int WeekId { get; set; }
        public int SubregionId { get; set; }
        public int YearId { get; set; }
    }
```

I create a Testcontroller which have two actions Index and Transfer.
In the Index Action i initialize the viewModel and pass the model to index View. In the Index View I use @Url.Action("Tranfer",Model) to pass model back to Transfer action.but in the Transfer action. i can't get the correct model.Can any body tell me the solution?

Thanks!!!

Comment: what does URL generated by your code look like?